# Is there a way to improve the model performance?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, regression

```
# Import the Required Libraries

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Regression/train.csv')

df1.shape

a = [x for x in df1.columns if df1[x].dtype == 'O']  # Categorical Columns
len(a)

b =  [x for x in df1.columns if df1[x].dtype != 'O']  # Numerical Columns
len(b)

df1[a]

df1[b]

# Filling the Categorical columns

def fill_in(dataset):
for i in dataset.columns:
    if dataset[i].isna and dataset[i].dtype == 'O':
        dataset[i].fillna('missing',inplace = True)
return dataset

fill_in(df1)

# Filling the Numerical columns



def filling_integer(dataset):
   for i in dataset.columns:
       if dataset[i].isna and dataset[i].dtype != 'O':
              dataset[i].fillna(dataset[i].median(),inplace = True)
    return dataset
filling_integer(df1)



sns.heatmap(df1.isna())

"""Check for Outliers"""

for i in b:
  plt.title(i)
  sns.boxplot(x=df1[i])
  plt.show()

"""Handling the outliers"""

!pip install feature-engine

from feature_engine.outliers import Winsorizer

# for Q-Q plots
import scipy.stats as stats

# create the capper

windsoriser = Winsorizer(capping_method='quantiles', # choose from iqr, gaussian or quantiles
                          tail='both', # cap left, right or both tails 
                          fold=0.05,
                          variables= list(df1[b]))

windsoriser.fit(df1)

df1_t = windsoriser.transform(df1)

# function to create boxplot.


def diagnostic_plots(df, variable):
    # function takes a dataframe (df) and
    # the variable of interest as arguments

    # define figure size
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 4))

    # boxplot
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
    sns.boxplot(y=df[variable])
    plt.title('Boxplot')

    plt.show()

diagnostic_plots(df1, 'SalePrice'),diagnostic_plots(df1_t, 'SalePrice')

diagnostic_plots(df1, 'WoodDeckSF'),diagnostic_plots(df1_t, 'WoodDeckSF')

df1.shape, df1_t.shape

df1_t.head().T

"""Converting Categorical into Numerical"""

for feature in a:
    labels_ordered=df1_t.groupby([feature])['SalePrice'].mean().sort_values().index
    labels_ordered={k:i for i,k in enumerate(labels_ordered,0)}
    df1_t[feature]=df1_t[feature].map(labels_ordered)

df1_t

"""Scale the Features"""

scale= [feature for feature in df1_t.columns if feature not in ['Id','SalePrice']]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler=MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(df1_t[scale])

scaler.transform(df1_t[scale])

data = pd.concat([df1_t[['Id', 'SalePrice']].reset_index(drop=True),
                    pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(df1_t[scale]), columns=scale)],axis=1)

data

X = data.drop(['Id','SalePrice'],axis=1)

y = data[['SalePrice']]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)

import tensorflow as tf

ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))

ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128,activation='relu'))

ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))

ann.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

ann.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 100)
```

I am using to ANN to solve House Price Regression Problem and the model is performing way too bad.The loss function is pretty high even though i tried with 100 epochs and with 2 hidden layers with 128 nodes in each of them. I still got a loss of

```
Epoch 100/100
35/35 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 633115520.0000
```

where did i go wrong .  Can someone help me understand it ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of links to code

Comment: @ForceBru Hi thanks for correcting me. I have updated the post . Do let me know where did i go wrong ?

Comment: Use this and check the accuracy also `ann.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])`

Comment: @PrakashDahal Hi. Thanks for responding i tried that way too the accuracy is very very bad.    Epoch 100/100
35/35 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 679746304.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Comment: Try removing `windsoriser` from the code and check what is the new accuracy

Comment: @PrakashDahal Epoch 100/100
35/35 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2317569792.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 . Is it due to using all the features ?

Comment: How many columns do you have? Try using SelectKBest to chose top 10 best features

Answer (score 0):

I think you should post this question in [Kaggle Discussion Forum](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/discussion) particular to this dataset or in general [discussion forum](https://www.kaggle.com/discussion).  Anyhow there is a lot of room to improve.

**Categorical Columns**

For example take `LotConfig` column you have labelled all classes to some numbers then model will understand that Inside is less preferable to Corner because Inside is given 0 and Corner to 0.25 in the dataset.

Model will give more preference to the `Corner` as it has the highest numerical value which will be biased towards that but in reality it should not

**Numerical Columns**

For every missing value in the numerical columns you had filled it with the `median` which is wrong which will distort the nature of the column. Suppose it has 60% missing values you are filling all those with median values will completely different what you had observer before. Missing values of each and every column has to be assessed and filled differently.

Note: Since it has lot of categorical columns and not many classes in each column probably tree based algorithms will work better